# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar los threads para mostrar animaciones al mismo tiempo?

Tags: java, algoritmos, hilos, jframe

Estoy haciendo un programa en java que muestra la animación de cuatro algoritmos de ordenamiento, pero estoy tratando de encontrar la forma de que se muestren al mismo tiempo y no tengan que esperar a que termine un proceso para iniciar otro.

Lo siguiente es parte de mi código que maneja la ejecución en el cual traté de utilizar Threads, pero de esta forma no me da animación alguna.

```
@Override
    public void run(){
        String com= this.getName();
        if("quicksort".equals(com)){
            try {
                jpanel1.desordenar();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel1.reiniciarColores();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel1.quickSort(jpanel1.A, 0, jpanel1.A.length-1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
         
        else if("heapsort".equals(com)){
            try {
                jpanel2.desordenar();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel2.reiniciarColores();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel2.heapSort(jpanel2.A);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
        
        else if("mergesortsl".equals(com)){
            try {
                jpanel3.desordenar();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel3.reiniciarColores();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel3.mergeSort(jpanel3.A, 0, jpanel3.A.length-1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
        
        else if("mergesortcl".equals(com)){
            try {
                jpanel4.desordenar();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel4.reiniciarColores();
                Thread.sleep(20);
                jpanel4.mergeSortListas(jpanel4.A, 0, jpanel4.A.length-1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Runnable runnable= new Grafica();
        Thread t1= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t2= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t3= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t4= new Thread(runnable);
        t1.setName("quicksort");
        t2.setName("heapsort");
        t3.setName("mergesortsl");
        t4.setName("mergesortcl");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
```

El programa es funcional (sin hilos), pero necesito que las animaciones se muestren al mismo tiempo.

Les agradezco de antemano a todos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código debería de funcionar bien

```
class Main implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        String com = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        if("quicksort".equals(com)){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                System.out.println("QuickSort");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        else if("heapsort".equals(com)){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                System.out.println("HeapSort");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        else if("mergesortsl".equals(com)){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                System.out.println("MergeSortSL");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        else if("mergesortcl".equals(com)){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                System.out.println("MergeSortCL");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable runnable= new Main();
        Thread t1= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t2= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t3= new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t4= new Thread(runnable);
        t1.setName("quicksort");
        t2.setName("heapsort");
        t3.setName("mergesortsl");
        t4.setName("mergesortcl");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

La diferencia de el código anterior con el tuyo es que este código implementa la interfaz `Runnable`. Supongo (no lo sé exactamente) que el tuyo extiende de `Thread` porque al principio de tu método `run()` tienes el siguiente código

> `String com= this.getName();`

Lo cual se me hizo raro, y por eso supuse que extiendes de Thread.

En fin, si extiendes de `Thread` y luego haces un nuevo thread de ese thread es algo extraño, y si luego seteas el nombre del thread, lo vas a setear pero en el nuevo thread que acabas de crear.

No está mal extender de thread, sólo que no es muy común y en ese caso hay que manejar de diferente forma los hilos.

En la solución que expuse mejor implementé `Runnable` y obtuve el nombre del hilo no con `this.getName()` (porque no hereda de Thread), sino con `Thread.currentThread().getName()`.

El output del código anterior es

```
QuickSort
HeapSort
MergeSortSL
MergeSortCL
QuickSort
HeapSort
MergeSortSL
MergeSortCL
...
QuickSort
HeapSort
MergeSortSL
MergeSortCL
```

El cual asumo que es el comportamiento deseado, pues se ejecutan de forma concurrente y no secuencial.

**Nota**: Que algo se ejecute *al mismo tiempo* es casi imposible, pues para ello se requeriría que las acciones se ejecutaran en diferentes cores o CPU's, pero podemos hacer (mediante hardware) que el tiempo de ejecución entre cada acción sea extremadamente pequeño, tanto, que sea imperceptible para nosotros los humanos, y parezca que se ejecutan *al mismo tiempo*.

Si los hilos se ejecutan en cores o CPU's separados, se dice que son **pararelos**, de lo contrario son **concurrentes**.

Comment: Sí tenía implementado Runnable. Pero existió una confusión con la finalidad de mi programa, ya que estoy trabajando con jframe y necesitaba que la animaciones se mostraran "al mismo tiempo". Aun así, lo que cambiaste funcionó a la perfección en mi código. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Ah, claro, es que JFrame extiende de Component, clase que también tiene un método [getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName()), entonces supongo que estabas invocando a ese método y no al de Thread, pero bueno, qué bueno que te sirvió la respuesta